# Aftereffects: How to create easing with Mask path changes?

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects

Alright I have a growing pill shape in AE that one frame where the width is very small, final frame has width pretty big. Just 2 frames.

I set keyframe interp to bezier, but Im getting a pretty linear change between the 2 sizes. Ive tried copy pasting easing expressions but they don't work because its changing a mask.

How can ease in and out 2 frames of a mask path?

Comment: did u used graph editor?